# What is the difference between the trainable_weights and trainable_variables in the tensorflow basic lstm_cell?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

While trying to copy the weights of a LSTM Cell in Tensorflow using the Basic LSTM Cell as documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell#class_basiclstmcell), i stumbled upon both the trainable_weights and trainable_variables property.

[Source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py) has not really been informative for a noob like me sadly. A little bit of experimenting did yield the following information though: 
Both have the exact same layout, being a list of length two, where the first entry is a tf.Variable of shape: (2*num_units, 4*num_units), the second entry of the list is of shape (4*num_units,), where num_units is the num_units from initializing the BasicLSTMCell. 
The intuitive guess for me is now, that the first list item is a concatenation of the weights of the four internal layers of the lstm, the second item being a concatenation of the respective biases, fitting the expected sizes of these obviously.

Now the question is, whether there is actually any difference between these? I assume they might just be a result of inheriting these from the rnn_cell class?

Comment: I want to point out that the shape of the first entry of the trainable_variable should be (num_units+num_inputs, 4*num_units), where num_inputs is the dimension of input to the LSTM cell. I am using tensorflow 1.7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the source code of the `Layer` class that `RNNCell` inherits from:

```
@property
def trainable_variables(self):
    return self.trainable_weights
```

See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py). The RNN classes don't seem to overwrite this definition -- I would assume it's there for special layer types that have trainable variables that don't quite qualify as "weights". Batch normalization would come to mind, but unfortunately I can't find any mention of `trainable_variables` in that one's source code (except for `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` which is different).

Comment: So i suppose, there is no difference to trainable-weights?

Comment: For these layers, no, since `trainable_variables` simply returns `trainable_weights`.