# In which cases we use the attribute trainable_variables over trainable_weights and vice-versa of a tf.keras.Model in TF2?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I was studying how to do transfer learning in TF 2 and I saw that at [this tutorial from Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#compile_the_model) they use the attribute `trainable_variables` to reference the trainable variables of a model but in this [other tutorial from the keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/) they use the attribute `trainable_weights` of a `tf.keras.Model`.

I checked both attributes with a simple model, and they give me the same result.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[64, 64, 3])

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

print("\nTrainable weights")
vars_model = [var.name for var in model.trainable_weights]
print(*vars_model, sep="\n")

print("\nTrainable variables")
vars_model = [var.name for var in model.trainable_variables]
print(*vars_model, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
2.2.0

Trainable weights
conv2d/kernel:0
conv2d/bias:0
batch_normalization/gamma:0
batch_normalization/beta:0

Trainable variables
conv2d/kernel:0
conv2d/bias:0
batch_normalization/gamma:0
batch_normalization/beta:0
```

I checked this [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49020732) and tried to follow the definition of both attributes: `trainable_variables` seems to be [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1971) and `trainable_weights` seems to be [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1072) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py#L566), since `td.keras.Model` also inherits from `network.Network`. The former seems to be returning the `trainable_weights` variable. But, I am not sure that this happens in "all" cases.

So, I am wondering in which cases we use `trainable_variables` over `trainable_weights` and vice-versa? and why?

Comment: Weirdly, it seems these attributes is not appearing in tf.keras.Model chapter.

Comment: From my understanding of Tensorflow's code base, `trainable_variables` is meant for the user-facing API, while `trainable_weights` is either reserved for the internal API for adding features in future versions, or is a reminant of past versions. Either way, as of now, both these are identical.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal, It makes sense that they come from past versions. What caught my attention was the use of these attributes in different and official documentation. For example, the link to the Keras docs., that uses `trainable_weights`, was updated in 05/2020. So, I thought that maybe they were used differently. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

They both are same in Tensorflow version 2.2.0. If you go into the source code of base layer - [tf.keras.layers.Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) (click on "View source on GitHub"), you can find the below assignment. **This is the class from which all layers inherit.**

```
  @property
  @doc_controls.do_not_generate_docs
  def trainable_variables(self):
    return self.trainable_weights

  @property
  @doc_controls.do_not_generate_docs
  def non_trainable_variables(self):
    return self.non_trainable_weights
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @K. Bogdan - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Thanks. So, as pointed by @SusmitAgrawal, they probably come from past versions, right? And maybe that is why they are used in different documentations of the framework.

Comment: Probably, yes. But couldn't find the documentation to support that statement. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The trainable_variables = trainable_weights. But, they are in the numbers of the matrices of the weights not like the trainable_parameters.